# Importing Fanciful Library using Maven (Minecraft Server Plugin Development)

Tags: java, maven, github, minecraft

So I have been trying to get the send raw chat messages to work and I have had no luck since everything I have used, wont work. Originally I didn't want to use a library but it seems I might have to try it since I have tried everything else.

I found a library called Fanciful that seems to have everything and it requires you importing it using Maven. I have looked around on how to import library using Maven but I haven't been able to do it. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Here's the GitHub Link: https://github.com/mkremins/fanciful

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Instructions are provided on the link you provided. Have you tried following them? If so, what happened?

Comment: @KErlandsson The only instructions are "Use Maven. Add the Fanciful repository and dependency entries to your pom.xml" These aren't really useful to me when I don't know how to do it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download and install library to your local repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\lib-{version}.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code 
-DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

[more about how to install custom library into Maven local repository](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to use Maven, you could also try to download the jar file from the repository directly. For example: [Fanciful 0.3.3](http://repo.franga2000.com/artifactory/public/mkremins/fanciful/0.3.3-SNAPSHOT/fanciful-0.3.3-20150330.224758-1.jar).

Comment: Oh ok, I actually tried looking for this and couldn't find it so gave up. I ended up turning to maven instead because I thought that was the only way. Thank you